# How to declare an optional ArrayList with elements inside....?

Tags: .net, vb.net, arraylist, optional-parameters

I have an interface like

```
Public Shared Function myfunction(Byval myvar as string, 
                               Optional ByVal myarray As ArrayList = Nothing) As String
```

but I want to declare an optional arraylist with default values... how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

Default parameter values must be compile-time constants; you cannot use an object instanec as a default value (except for strings).

Instead, you can check whether it's `Nothing` inside the function, and, if so, populate it with defaults.

Comment: @Brad: No you didn't.  `ParamArray` cannot be used to provide a non-empty set of default values.

Comment: That having been said I don't see why mellamokb's answer isn't exactly what was asked for.

Comment: @Chris: That's exactly what I meant at the end, except with an overload instead of an optional parameter.

Comment: then it's impossible also to pass an array of strings as an optional parameter bc it's always an object, right?

Answer (score 6):

You could use overloading instead

```
Public Shared Function myfunction(ByVal myvar as String) As String
    Dim myArray as ArrayList = new ArrayList()
    '' populate here
    Return myFunction(myvar, myarray)
End Function

Public Shared Function myfunction(ByVal myvar as string, _
    ByVal myarray as ArrayList) As String

End Function
```

Comment: +1 for actually solving the OP's problem, not simply saying it can't be done.